# Most important original features in PCA: can one multiply eigenvectors by the explained variance?

Tags: pca, feature-selection

I would like to know the importance of the original features in principle component analysis. See [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422201/most-important-original-features-of-principle-component-analysis) for an example of what I mean (with a code example).

The question is: can you multiply the factor loadings [meaning the corresponding eigenvector] of a PC by the explained variance of the PC to assess the importance of features in a PCA?

Comment: What is the purpose of the feature selection you are trying to do?

Comment: Note that what you call "factor loadings" are simply PCA eigenvectors (I edited to clarify). "Loadings" is something else: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905 - namely eigenvectors scaled by the square roots of the respective eigenvalues. So you have basically reinvented the loadings.

Comment: I would like to know which original features contributed most to the PCA distribution. In that way, I could better explain the PCA distribution