# How can it be that almost all the variance is explained by the first PC?

Tags: variance, pca, matlab

I have a data matrix $X$ and I perform a PCA on this data with:

```
%// Subtract the mean from the data
Y = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X));

%// Obtain the PCA solution by calculate the SVD of Y
[U, S, V] = svd(Y);

%// Compute variance explained
rho = diag(S).^2./sum(diag(S).^2);

%// Plot variance explained
plot(rho, 'o-')
title('Variance explained by principal components');
xlabel('Principal component');
ylabel('Variance explained');
```

I get this plot

[image]

What is the reason for this to happen? It cannot be correct that only the first PC can explain all the variance.

My data looks like

```
price       crime      nox        rooms      dist          radial  proptax    stratio   lowstat   lprice     lnox      lproptax
==========================================================================================================================
24000       .006       5.38       6.57       4.09          1       29.6       15.3       4.98   10.08581   1.682688    5.69036  
21599       .027       4.69       6.42       4.97          2       24.2       17.8       9.14   9.980402   1.545433   5.488938  
34700       .027       4.69       7.18       4.97          2       24.2       17.8       4.03    10.4545   1.545433   5.488938  
33400       .032       4.58          7       6.06          3       22.2       18.7       2.94   10.41631   1.521699   5.402678  
...
```

so the values of first attribute are much higher than the rest. Can this be the reason to the weird "variance explained" plot?

Comment: Yes. The "total variance" of your dataset is simply the sum of the variances of all the variables. Your `price` variable will dominate the sum, and hence the PC1 will essentially equal to `price` and will explain almost all the variance. You probably want to run PCA on correlations not on covariances (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53), i.e. you probably should standardize your data after centering but prior to doing SVD: `Y = bsxfun(@times, Y, 1./std(Y));`

Comment: But I thought I was standardizing with `Y = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X));`?

Comment: No, that's just centering. The variances can still be very different, check for yourself by running `var(Y)`.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks! But you say that `price` will dominate the sum, and hence the PC1 will be equal to `price`.. As I have understood I cannot say that PC1 is related to any of the variables. Am I right?

Comment: PC1 is just a linear combination of your original variables. Of course you can see how they are related. If you don't standardize, it will be $\sim1$ times `price` plus $\sim 0$ times everything else.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87037/which-variables-explain-which-pca-components-and-vice-versa for another example in which uncritical use of covariance matrix produced garbage, which was not even noticed by all contributors to the thread.

Comment: After some reflection, I edited the top answer in the "PCA on correlation or covariance" thread (to include some plots) and I think this question is now a duplicate of that one. In the dataset considered there PCA on covariance explains over 98% of the variance.